# How to logout from any function outside a controller action in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

I have been trying to log out using :

```
Route::get('/myland',function(){
Auth::logout();
Session::flush();
});
```

But the user is not being logged out. In my scenario I am obliged to logout that way without using controller I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Are you sure your route function is getting called? 
Did you tried some dd() inside the function to ensure that it is called properly?

Comment: Yes it is being called. I have even added Auth::check() and it passed that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AuthController/loginController constructor add below code

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
}
```

or

```
Route::get('/myland', function(){
   Auth::logout();
   return redirect('/');
});
```